# How to use inversion of control for a series of processes dependent on user input and each other?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

### Intro

I am working in C# with a homebrew dependency injection framework (perhaps an arrogant mistake of mine, currently considering switching to Ninject).

I have 3 processes, represented by classes:

#### GetInput

This is responsible for getting user input via a GUI. The GUI displays the desired values with input fields and returns the user input to the process. Its dependencies are: a GUI controller and what values I want it to get (e.g. "Foo").

#### BuildFile

This is responsible for mapping a series of values to keys in a template. The template contains some text, this class fills in the gaps and returns the completed file. Its dependencies are: a template file, static key-values (constants) and dynamic key-values where the values should come from the GetInput process.

#### WriteFile

This is responsible for writing a file to disk. Its dependencies are: a file path and the file content, where the file content should come from the BuildFile process.

### Desired Situation

I want to be able to configure combinations of these 3 processes for different file types. For example:

#### ConfigurationA

`GetInput("Foo", "Bar") returns UserInput1, UserInput2`
`BuildFile(TemplateFileContent, {"StaticKey", "StaticValue"}, {"Foo", UserInput1}, {"Bar", UserInput2}) returns FileContent`
`WriteFile("C:/Some/Path.txt", FileContent)`

### Current Situation

I am trying to build these configurations in the composition root of my application, and I just can't get it to work. The dependency on user input makes it impossible to resolve the dependencies until the user input is given, and the dependency of each process on the previous one is also a challenge.

### Questions

How would you go about linking up these dependencies?

Is there a DI pattern I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

If your user input is not available at the time of resolution then you either need to change your app so that it gets the input and then uses it to resolve the dependency, or you need to beef up your framework by using an aspect to "intercept" when certain methods/events on the GetInput class fire. Basically you'll want to wire up BuildFile to the point in time when user input becomes available.

Having said all of that, your classes appear to behave not so much as objects but more like housing procedural code that executes sequentially which is I think where most of your problem is coming from. You could probably simplify your code by combining BuildFile and WriteFile into one class called FileBuilder, and expose the write functionality via a method named Write(), for example.

Edit:
If you go the route of interception, you should probably start using an existing DI framework because it will be challenging to roll your own. As for the implementation of it, you'll want to create a factory method that returns a specific instance of the FileBuilder dependency based on the input. That can either be done inside the interceptor by inspecting at the input and calling resolution of a specific instance of the FileBuilder, or, as I generally prefer in order to have better separation of concerns, pass the input along to the resolution of the BuildFile dependency and let the returned instance be determined by a factory method wired up to the BuildFile registration. It's valid to allow a factory method sitting in the DI registration code to know specifics about the implementation of an interface.

Comment: Your second paragraph is something I have already done. It works fine, and solves the dependency issue between the BuildFile process and the WriteFile process, but not the user input dependency.

Comment: As for the first paragraph, how would it look to 'get the input and then use it to resolve the dependency'? Do you know any examples that do this or something similar? I will do some research on other frameworks to see if they offer the 'aspect interception' you mention.

Comment: It depends on what framework/stack your application is using and how far up you are registering your objects. Assuming you're writing a web app, if you're using ASP.NET MVC and you are registering your controllers/views, you would wire up the dependency resolution inside an interceptor bound to a controller/view method where the input is being passed in. Castle Windsor is the most robust for this pattern, Ninject has an extension that allows you to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: If you are using WebForms or your controllers/views aren't being registered, you have to use the service locator pattern to resolve your dependency at the top level passing in the input. Instead of the call to Resolve for dependencies sitting outside of the pages/forms, you would have to do something like `var input = GetSomeInput(); Resolve<FileBuilder>(input);` inside your GetInput class if your GetInput class is handling all of the UI.